# How to format date in SSRS?

Tags: date, reporting-services, format

In SSRS report query is generating date as a column in the format of :

**Sales   ID20200331      ID20200430      ID20200531**

To remove the ID i used following expression:
=Right( Fields!ID20210331.Value, len(Fields!ID20210331.Value) - 2)
This gives me 84, instead of removing ID.

How can I remove ID and format date as 2020 Mar etc.

Thanks

Comment: Your field value is ID20200331 or is that the field name?

Answer (score 0):

If your fields values are "ID20200430" etc then in SSRS you can use something like this..

```
=DateSerial(
MID(Fields!IDDate.Value, 3, 4),
MID(Fields!IDDate.Value, 7, 2),
RIGHT(Fields!IDDate.Value, 2)
)
```

**However** It appears that it's your column [names] that represent dates is this correct?

If this is true, then you would have to UNPIVOT the columns in SQL then convert the resulting values into a real date format.

Here' some sample data to show how to do this.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Sales varchar(10), ID20200331 int, ID20200430 int, ID20200531 int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('A', 1,2,3),
('B', 4,5,6),
('C', 7,8,9)

SELECT 
        Sales, IdDate, SomeNumber 
        , MyDate = DATEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING(IdDate, 3, 4), SUBSTRING(IdDate, 7, 2), SUBSTRING(IdDate, 9, 2))
    FROM @t
    UNPIVOT(
            SomeNumber FOR IdDate IN ([ID20200331],[ID20200430],[ID20200531])
    ) unpvt
```

Which gives us this including the myDate column which is the correct date type

[image]

You could then use this in a matrix control in SSRS to get the data back into a pivoted view